# Simultaneous Equations where I let $x + y = 5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have the following system of equations
$$ x + y + z = 8, \quad xy + yz + xz = 9, \quad xyz = -18$$

I have been given a substitution $x + y = 5$. But I am not sure why or where I can infer this from? Could someone suggest a starting point?

Comment: It's not clear to me how was "$x+y=5$" given to you. Is the problem to solve algebraic system $x + y + z = 8, xy + yz + xz = 9, xyz = -18$ and solution starts with assuming that $x+y = 5$?

Comment: Use Vieta's formulas

Comment: @Ennar, it is in an example that I am working through. I am to solve the question that you mentioned in the earlier post. In the example, $x + y = 5$ isn't mentioned, just the system I mentioned above. And then in the solution $x + y = 5$  is mentioned without explanation.

Comment: @MathAttack I will go on to use that method, thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: I can't tell you where it comes from without seeing complete solution that person made. The way you wrote it, it doesn't follow directly, some work is needed to establish the fact. It is equivalent to saying $z = 3$ and not all solutions need to have $z = 3$, so some breaking of symmetry occurred (probably assuming $x\leq y\leq z$ or something similar) which needs to be reintroduced later. Also, Another User gave you a solution using Vieta's formulas in their now deleted answer, but you kind of dismissed it.

Comment: We have $x+y = 8-z$ and $(x+y)z = 9-xy = 9+18/z$, and writing $u = x+y$, we deduce $u(8-u) = 9+\frac{18}{8-u}$, so this would be one way to directly find $x+y$.

Comment: @Ennar the solution I have is as follows So we have $x + y + z = 8$. Letting $x + y = 5$, therefore $5 + z = 8$, therefore $z = 3$. then, the rest of the solution follows by working through the rest of the equations which agrees with all the methods below.

Comment: @Prasiortle, as it's clear from your answer, $x+y$ is not actually uniquely determined. It's equivalent to saying $z = 3$, so whoever was solving this made some assumption that breaks symmetry, and that symmetry needs to be reintroduced at the end.

Comment: @Ennar Yes ... but strangely, it's not the usual WLOG $x \leq y \leq z$ (or $x \geq y \geq z$), since as seen from my answer below, the values are $-1, 3, 6$, so you would need the $-1$ and the $6$ to get a sum of $5$.

Comment: @Prasiortle I was just guessing, I didn't solve the cubic when I wrote that. That's why I said "or something similar". But yeah, something weird is going on, but OP doesn't provide source so we can't say anything about it.

Comment: @Ennar your initial solution was exactly how I have it in my solution. I think I just have a badly written problem statement with no justifications in the solutions provided to me.

Comment: @Ennar Indeed, I tried messing around with a bunch of inequalities before realising based on the actual solution that $x \leq y \leq z$ or similar wasn't gonna work ... I agree we'd need to see the full solution the OP possesses to fully explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Vieta's formulae, if $r_1, r_2, r_3$ are the roots of a cubic polynomial $t^3+at^2+bt+c$, then $$r_1+r_2+r_3 = -a, \qquad r_1r_2+r_2r_3+r_3r_1 = b, \qquad \text{and} \qquad r_1r_2r_3 = -c.$$
Therefore, in your example, $x,y,z$ are roots of the equation $$t^3-8t^2+9t+18 = 0 \iff (t-3)(t^2-5t-6) = 0 \\ \iff (t+1)(t-3)(t-6) = 0,$$ i.e. $x,y,z = -1,3,6$ in some order.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In the solution I have, $x + y = 5 $ is given without explanation and I wasn't provided it in the original example problem statement.

Comment: Yeah I see - does my further comment (on your original question above) help?

Comment: It's not actually in some exact order. Any order for them works

Comment: Yes, that does. I see where it comes from!

Answer (score 0):

From $$xyz = -18$$
$$xy = \frac{-18}{z}$$
and
$$x+y=8-z$$

Substituting this in the second equation:
$$xy+z(y+x)=9$$
$$\frac{-18}{z}+z(8-z)=9$$
This forms a cubic which bringing into the standard form is:
$${z}^{3}-8{z}^{2}+9z+18=0$$
which on solving gives:
$$(z-6)(z-3)(z+1)=0$$
$$\therefore z = 6, 3, -1$$

If $z=6$ then,
$$x+y=2$$
and
$$y=2-x$$
Putting this in the second equation:
$$x(2-x)+6(2-x)+6x=9$$
Solves to
$$x=-1,3$$

If $x=-1$ then $y=3$
If $x=3$ then $y=-1$

Similarly on solving for the other values of $z$ for $x$ and $y$ we get that:
$$x=-1,3,6$$
and
$$y=3,-1,6$$

The fact that $x+y=5$ which was mentioned in the question was one of the solutions of z and hence was only partly mentioned.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @Ennar Although I agree with you, I suspect that this is what whoever made this exercise had in mind.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I tried to find out what's going on exactly in the comments below the question, but I'm still not sure, and I'm even less sure that OP knows what's going on even after they were given answer based on their comments, but ok. We can't win all of them, I guess.

Comment: @Ennar you are correct. I went through the question again and edited the before mentioned solution.